# Autowire beans from library project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working with SpringBoot 3 and I have my library a jar and a running application in spring.
The application autowired component in the library, like Entity as example. I achieve this adding this:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.acme.library.entity"})
```

in the main application class of my running application.
So far so good, now I add a repository in the library and an entity linked to the repository, I create a service always inside my library, and I want to autowired the repository inside the service.
I read a lot of already posted messages and did this:

[image]

I add the imports file under META-INF/spring and create a AutoConfigure class with this code:

```
@AutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class AutoConfigure {
    // intentionally left empty
}
```

Then in the pom.xlm of my running application I add this:

```
 <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.imports</include>
                    <include>*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

        </resources>
```

But when I run the app I got this error message:

> Field acmeRepository in
> com.acme.library.service.jobrunner.DefaultJobRunnerService required a
> bean of type 'com.acme.library.repository.AcmeRepository' that could
> not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.earnext.common.repository.FamilyRepository' in your
> configuration.

Comment: This has nothing to do with resource filtering or adding autoconfiguration imports to your resources.  Simply add the library as a dependency and add a `@ComponentScan` that includes the packages in the dependency that you want to scan.

Comment: I'm a newbie and probably I explain the my problem in a bad way, myapologise.  I cannot autowire beans from my custom library. The library is a Spring non-runnable jar, that consists primarily of domain Entities and Repositories. It doesn't have runnable Application.class

Comment: It's relatively simple; just include the dependency and in your configuration class, add ComponentScan to include beans (Service, Component, Controller, etc), this may even pickup your Repositories if they're annotated with @Repository, if not, see the answer from Wladimir.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

```
@AutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.library.repository")
@ComponentScan
public class AutoConfigure {
    // intentionally left empty
}
```